# How to extract search results on a website into local file

Tags: python, r, web

I am trying to get list of all patent numbers from US patents website that matches my search query. The result in the example query below has a total of ~700 entries. The page shows only 50 entries at a time and there is no way I can increase this number.

One way is to copy all the 50 entries at a time and paste into MS excel and repeat this until the last page. This method is time consuming and frustrating. Is there an efficient way to get the whole list programmatically (preferably Python or R) or all at once.

http://appft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO2&Sect2=HITOFF&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsearch-adv.html&r=0&p=1&f=S&l=50&Query=ACLM%2F%28%22TRANSCRIPTION+FACTORS%22%29&d=PG01

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **Mechanize** and **BeautifulSoup4** to do this with Python.  They are relatively easy to install.  You can use libraries other than Mechanize to browse the internet, but I find that it's pretty easy to use.  You can also use the **Shelve** module to store bits of information in a python-readable (dictionary) format.

The entirety of the code will be 100+ lines depending on how much information you want to get.

Generally, here's how you would code the program:

1. Create a browser object with `br=mechanize.Browser()`
2. Use the browser to open a page up using `r=br.open(url)`
3. Read the html of the page using `html=r.read()`
4. Use BeautifulSoup to parse the html into a readable format `soup=BeautifulSoup(html)`
5. Use `soup.findAll()` to find html elements which contain links to the pages you want.  To get the pattern for what objects in the html contain this information, I'd recommend using an internet browser to inspect the html elements and source code.  That way you know what you're looking for.  Sometimes it's a bit tricky, as things are indexed differently on different, but similar pages.

You can keep on repeating steps 2-5 with new urls whenever you need to get more information.  This is how you can navigate the page at the bottom (you are limited to 50 entries per page, but you can navigate them automatically).

Here is some sample code of a web crawler I have:

```
url_dict=shelve.open(html_filename)
#opens webpage  
r=br.open(first_url)
for i in range(1,20):
    #navigates upper browser to next page for non-first-pages
    if (i !=1):
        r=br.open(first_url+str(i)+'_p/')
    #collects list of urls to be navigated by sr
    html=r.read()
    soup=BeautifulSoup(html)
    frames=soup.find_all("a",{"class":br_class})#br_class is defined globally
    time.sleep(1)
    for item in frames:
        url_suffix=item['href']
        full_url=url_prefix+url_suffix
        full_url=full_url.encode('ascii','ignore')
        if str(full_url) not in url_dict:
            url_dict[str(full_url)]=get_information(full_url,sr)
        time.sleep(1)
```

The get_information() method looks at various urls and returns a dictionary of information.  This is stored in a file (using the shelve module), so I can write it to a human-readable file later. Since you're only looking at patent numbers, this probably isn't necessary.

After you've done all that, you can write to a csv file with Python.

Here is a tab-delimited csv-creator I made for my crawler.  I still need to debug it, but the general layout is correct.

```
def parse_data():
    data=shelve.open(html_filename)
    with open(out_file,'w') as out_handle:
        line = '\t'
        for item in header_list:
            line=line+item+'\t'
        out_handle.write(line)
        for url in data:
            line=""
            for item in header_list:
                line=line+data[item]+'\t'
                out_handle.write(line)
    print("Done writing data")
    data.close()
```

After you make the file, you can run it on the windows command line using `python [filename]` while in the correct directory.